# Jquery Randomizing within Categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

so here is my question in a situation if you will.
i have 6 items in div classes which correspond to 3 categories
something like this

```
class ="boat"
class ="car"
class ="bike"
class ="blueboat"
class ="redcar"
class ="greenbike"
```

so is there a jquery/javascript approach with `.addClass` where when someone clicks on the button "Randomize" it adds class `.mine` to each one of the 3 categories ie `blueboat.mine` and `redcar.mine` and `bike.mine` but not `boat` or `car` or `greenbike` because they are in the same category?

Or another situation rather than `.addClass` use a jquery/javascript so when "Randomize" is clicked to randomly show 3 out of 6 items one in each category of `boat`, `car`, `bike` and hide the rest `blueboat`, `redcar`, `greenbike`. in this situation all 6 items are on the page when document is ready but with the randomize only 3 are left one from each category.

please let me know if anyone has any ideas or needs further clarification any help
is greatly appreciated.

thank you
-david

**edit: maybe this image will help out https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/rand.jpg?w=fc89ef22
I have added three categories A/B/C in those categories i have three items, A)car,boat,bike B)dog,cat,mouse C)Apple, Orange,Kiwi.. so when user clicks Randomize it randomly selects one item from each category (A,B,C) and adds the class .mine to each one of them. so i random and get car,dog,orange (.mine) for each. then i click randomize again and get something else ie: boat,mouse,kiwi there is a possible only 27 combinations for this idea... i hope this clarifies my intents..hopefully it did not complicate matters more.**

Comment: has ur class contain red, green, blue name as prefix or any other prefix?

Answer (score 1):

may be this helps [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bcLhw/1/)

**update**

you can use `toggle` see the [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bcLhw/3/)

Comment: thats awesome is there a way to make, it change to boat, redcar, bike for example on the next time you click randomize, so each time you click its a different set of 3 items highlighted? thank you so much

Comment: i have edited the original question above and added a visual hopefully the edit makes more sense...

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify it a bit, what are the three categoires, if classes are of 6 items

let there categories means 3 classes, "bike" , "boat" , "car", for specialization you should add specific class to this like "red bike", instead of "redBike"

According to my assumption this is the answer,

```
function (){
   var category = ["car" , "boat" , "bike"];
   for( var i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
    var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * 2);
    $( "div#id ." +  category[i]).eq(rand).addClass("highlight"); 
   }
   }
```

Comment: I have given it fully, now @3nigma, thank you ! My reputation is not  good (< 50 ) enough to comment; :(

Comment: I would +1 for this being the only answer that doesn't require the OP to go offsite (jsFiddle has a tendency to go offline), except that I can see two problems; 1) `.[rand]` should be `[rand]` and 2) Using array indexes on jQuery objects gives you direct access to the unwrapped element, so `addClass()` wouldn't be exposed.  Using `.eq(rand)` instead of `[rand]` should solve that problem.  A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example wouldn't go amiss too, it might help you get votes if you can show your code works.

Comment: the three categories are car bike and boat, there are in this situation 6 items car,bike,boat,redcar,greenbike,blueboat i would like to randomly add the .mine class to only one of each category ie. car.mine so not redcar or greenbike so not bike. that way your end result is always three items out of in this case 6... if that helps out

Answer (score 0):

take a look here [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2MVKa/)

Here i change the background color of *divs* which have class `car`, `bike` and `boat`

**[Reference](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/)**

Comment: thank you so much, but i was also wondering if possible to randomize the three choices each time the user clicks the "Randomize" button ie. 1st time its redcar,boat,greenbike 2nd time its car,blueboat,bike...etc